# Lüroth's theorem for transcendence degree two

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, field-theory, transcendence-degree

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, 
and $k \subsetneq L \subseteq k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ a field of transcendence degree two over $k$.
According to the comments of ulrich and abx in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287000/generalizations-of-l%C3%BCroth-theorem), there exist 
$h_1,h_2 \in k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $L=k(h_1,h_2)$.

> (1) Could one please give a reference to a proof of this result, preferrably a pure algebraic proof.

(The proof [here](http://ajwilson.co.uk/files/maths/luroth-problem.pdf) is not pure algebraic; of course, I mean the proof for transcendence degree two. The proof of transcendence degree one, presented in page 4, is pure algebraic).

Moreover, inspired by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190920/any-two-bivariate-algebraically-dependent-polynomials-are-always-in-the-same-rin/191058#191058):

> (2) Is it possible to find $h_1,h_2 \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: A term to search: "Castelnuovo's theorem".

Comment: Thank you very much; I will search "Castelnuovo's theorem" (it seems to appear in the notes I mentioned above, on page 8). Please, do you know the answer to my second question (2)?